# same data binding for diffrent users connecting to the sae angular js 2 web app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm new to angular js (version 2)

I have a page that use somme ng models, if I publish that angular js web app, people that connect to that same instance (same ip adress, ex : xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/home) they will have the same binding, if one is connected in russia and update a given ng model, one another in usa with see the modifications in real time.

My wish is that when someone connect to my angular web app, will get a page with unique scopes....

my question is what is the right way to get to this ?.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I know the reason , it's because I'm using lite-server that is using browsersync with node js, this tools are synchronizing all my browsers, I should switch to another server that handle production mode because lite-server is only for dev mode thanks you all

more info : https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/162`here`

Answer (score 0):

The state of your Angular app will be unique (scope, variables, etc.) to each user connected unless you rely in some backend code. Since you haven't mentioned anything about the backend I guess you are just using client side code and, perhaps, misunderstood how Angular works.

In a nutshell: Angular is code that runs in the users' browser, so all the program state is unique to each user connected to your app. Your users cannot see the modifications other users do without a backend.

Comment: i will give you more information :

I have an angular js 2  web app build with node.js, suppose it's hosted in my local machine under that url : 192.168.0.10:3000/home

when i use the same url on other machine under the same network, and i modify an input with an ng model, the other page in the other machine get the same update.

I'm thinking about the day where I host it and 10 users use the same page.

is there a way that let each user connected to that instante get a unique  instance ?

Comment: @BachirBouacheria but are you handling the models (ng-models) with Node? I mean if when a user updates a model, are you sending that update to the server and delivering it to the other clients? If not (I guess you are not doing that), then you are fine; the scenario you described will work as you desire. it doesn't matter that all your clients are using the same url because the client code (Angular) state is unique to each user (to each browser). In other words: have you tried what you have described? It shouldn't give you any problems.

Comment: @EnriqueMarcos : yes we are using angular js 2 with node js, so I guess the models are being sent to the server, this is why all the clients connecting to the port that the node js server is listening on see the same page rendering, in some one type on an input that have ng model, the other one see the taping in real time,

is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: @AmarAttilaZz Ok. Easy: just stop sending the updates to other clients :p. Without any code is kind of difficult to know exactly what's going on. Perhaps if you upload some pseudocode or something.

Comment: @EnriqueMarcos please check my answer bellow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take for example the quick start projet  [of angular js 2 availible in github](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md).

You can download it and run npm start on its folder :

the app url will start : http://localhost:3000/dashboard

if you open the url from another navigator or another machine on the same network, and you start playing around by typing on an input, the same update will occur on that input served from different navigator.

So, what is the solution ?